# Area Splitting Option Disabled

Tags: interface

When I opened a .blend file [Not mine someone else saved it], There is only one work area.

There the Area Split option context menu looks Disabled(greyed out). How can I enable it?

[image: Area Options menu]

Comment: If you open Blender with a new scene and then use File > Open to select the Blend file you can press N or click the top-right gear icon in the file selector to show the settings. Uncheck the Load UI option and the file will load with your default window layout rather than the one that is saved in the blend file.

Comment: Yes it worked (Unchecked the Load UI option in the File Open Dialog), thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be, area is maximized. Press View -> Area -> Toggle maximize area (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) to get maximized state back.

Or simply press "Back to Previous" button:

[image]

Comment: Does that work if the file has been saved in the maximised state though?

Comment: Yep. Why are you asking? It is easy to check

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure whether it would go back to the normal layout in that case, but having just tried it I see that it does.

Comment: Yes, my file was `maximized`. (Ctrl+Space) brought back it to the normal view.